# jQuery doesnt invoke alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON(
            "/myServer/getAllWidgets",
            function(data) {
                var optionsHTML = "<select id='widget-sel'>";
                optionsHTML += "<option selected='selected' id='default'>Select an option</option>";
                var len = data.length;
                for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    optionsHTML += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">'
                        + data[i] + '</option>';
                }

                optionsHTML += "</select>";

                $('#widget-sel-div').html(optionsHTML);
            }
        );

        $("#widget-sel").change(function() {
            alert("Hello!");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="widget-sel-div"></div>
```

So, the idea is that when `document.ready` fires, it populates the `widget-sel-div` with a select box (`widget-sel`) and then creates a change handler for that select that simply prints "Hello!" to the screen via alertbox.

When I run this, I get no errors (Firebug doesn't complain at all) and the select gets populated with all my widgets from the AJAX call to `/myServer/getAllWidgets`. *The problem is*, the change handler isn't working: when I select a widget I don't get the alertbox. Can anybody spot where I'm going awrye? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need ); after your $("#widget-sel").change(function() {
            alert("Hello!");
        }

  I mean it seems like you're not closing your change event with );

Comment: Sorry @Xeano (and everyone else) - that was a typo on my part from creating this question. The actual code is correct and I have updated the snippet above to reflect that.

Comment: That's fine :) the problem is described below,  $.getJSON is asnychroneous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time the code runs, the `#widget-sel` element doesn't exist in the DOM, because you add it in the callback to `getJSON` (which is asynchronous). You can't bind an event handler to it when it doesn't exist yet.

To get around this, you can delegate the event handler higher up the DOM tree (looks like you can use the parent `div` in this case) with the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (jQuery 1.7+, if you're using an older version, use `.delegate()` instead):

```
$("#widget-sel-div").on("change", "#widget-sel", function () {
    alert("Hello!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @James Allardice (+1) - please see my comment underneath Rory's answer - I have the same question for you. Thanks again!

Comment: @HeineyBehinds - You're welcome :) Yes, your example in your comment on Rory's answer is exactly correct. The important bit to note is the fact that there are no parentheses following the function identifier - you need to pass a *reference* to the function, rather than the return value of it.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of the AJAX call. The `change` handler will be executed before the AJAX call has completed and therefore there will be no element in the DOM for it to bind to. Instead, place the `change` in the AJAX call back:

```
$.getJSON(
    "/myServer/getAllWidgets",
    function(data) {
        var optionsHTML = "<select id='widget-sel'>";
        optionsHTML += "<option selected='selected' id='default'>Select an option</option>";
        var len = data.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            optionsHTML += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
        }
        optionsHTML += "</select>";

        $('#widget-sel-div').html(optionsHTML);
        $("#widget-sel").change(function() {
            alert("Hello!");
        }
    }
);
```

Or alternatively you can leave the `change` handler where it is and delegate the event listener to a static parent element like this:

```
 $('#widget-sel-div').on('change', '#widget-sel', function() {
      alert("Hello!");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan (+1) - the actual change handler is going to be pretty big. Can I define a function somewhere else (outside of document.ready) and then call it from inside the AJAX callback? So instead of  `$("#widget-sel").change(function() ...` have `$("#widget-sel").change(myFunc);`? If so is that the correct syntax?

Comment: @HeineyBehinds That would work well and your syntax is correct too :)

Comment: @JamesAllardice I seem to have been serially downvoted for the last few days.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Strange. Hopefully the fraudulent vote detection scripts will pick it up. Have a +1 to make up for it in the meantime :)